# Jenkins: Pipeline upstream trigger stop working at multibranch project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins multibranch pipeline projects.

1st must be triggered by the Github and by the 2nd one success build.

2nd must be triggered by the Github only.

I added `Properties` to Jenkinsfiles (*no upstream for 2nd of course*)

```
properties([
// Builds rotation
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10')),
    disableConcurrentBuilds(),
// Git project
    [$class: 'GithubProjectProperty', displayName: '', projectUrlStr: G_giturl],
// Trigger build from:
    pipelineTriggers([upstream(G_artifactsource), githubPush()])
])
```

The new properties appeared at graphical interface and all worked fine, for awhile. 
[image: Build triggers picture of Jenkins interface]

I do not know what i did, or maybe did nothing, but now all "Build Triggers" of all branches are empty. Github webhooks are still working, but not the upstream triggers. For testing purposes i made two new repos and did the same projects for them. New projects work good. 
There is no  "apply" buttons inside branches at the Multibranch projects, I can't add or delete build triggers by interface. Changing of Jenkinsfiles don't help too.
Is it bug or i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

No "properties" for multibranch. Only "options" and "triggers"

Next code works fine.

```
    pipeline {
            agent none
                triggers {
                    upstream G_artifactsource
                }
                options {
                    buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10')
                    disableConcurrentBuilds()
                }
....
```